# Frame handling in Webdriver IO

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium, automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am testing a webpage that has multiple forms in it.

When I use

```
client.frame({id:client.element('#frameId')});
```

I don't get any error, but when I try to interact with an element within that frame I get a **RuntimeError** telling me the element could not be located.

I have been looking out for literature about how the `frame()` method works but I don't have any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also using webdriver.io and it looks like documentation is a bit wrong.

You can access frames:

1) via it's number on the page. For example the first frame met in HTML DOM is 
`client.frame(0)`, second `client.frame(1)` etc

2) via name attribute:
`<frame name="test"></frame>`
`client.frame('test')`

3) find the element with `client.element('css_selector')`, then in a callback pass the returned value to the `.frame()`

Comment: Somehow neither of the techniques work.

My iframe is within a div. I hope that doesn't cause any issue.

Answer (score 3):

The way to go to a new frame is:

```
client.frame(<id of frame here>)
```

What you have should work too though. Try doing a `client.waitForExist` on an element that only exists on the frame, instead of just switching to frame and immediately trying to interact with element in that frame, as you may be firing your interaction event before selenium has had a chance to fully switch to the frame:

```
client.frame(<id of frame here>
client.waitForExist(<id of some css element that only exists in the frame>)
```

Answer (score 2):

`client.frame(<name_of_frame>)` worked.

I tried using a selector like `#idOfSelector` but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
const frameValue = browser.element('frame_selector').value;
browser.frame(frameValue);
```

Hopefully, it works for you.

Comment: In May 2015 (date of the question) webdriverio v2.4.5 was current. I can confirm that this answer works for v4.14.2.