# Having an issue interacting with pop-up window Webdriverio

Tags: javascript, selenium, paypal, webdriver-io, ava

I'm trying to interact with a pop-up PayPal window during my testing using selenium and webdriverio (I'm also using AVA as the test runner).  I'm able to switch to the pop-up and when I test if a form element is enabled it returns true.  However when I go to set the value of that element I get back this error message :

[image: Console Message 1]

Here is my code:

```
await client
  .window(windowId.paypal)
  .waitForExist('#paypalLogo', 5000)
  .pause(3000)
  .setValue('input#email', 'xxxxxx');
```

When I use:

```
const isEnabled = await client
  .window(windowId.paypal)
  .waitForExist('#paypalLogo', 5000)
  .pause(3000)
  .isEnabled('input#email');

console.log(isEnabled);

t.true(isEnabled);
```

I get back [image: Console result 2]

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: The answer suggested below fixed my issue.  I also used answers provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30081749/frame-handling-in-webdriver-io to help with handling iframes in webdriverio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check this issue? https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/issues/199

I think it's probably due to the fact that the login form is in an iframe.